# Формат gif

Tags: c#

Привет всем.

Подскажете, пожалуйста, есть ли способ загрузки формата GIF в picture Box?
 Формат GIF. Это анимационная картинка. Если ее просто поставить в picture Box, то она не будет анимированная.

Comment: @геннадий писарев, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: вы не умеете кидать контролы на форму и загружать в них изображения?

> Если ее просто поставить в picture Box. То она не будет анимированная

ну неправда же - вполне анимированная. Сам проверял

Comment: Ну я же не просто так задавал такой вопрос. Значит что-то не так делаю, вот и пришел за советом

Comment: и как же вы делаете?

Comment: Кидаю на форму pictureBox. И в свойствах pictureBox подключаю ссылку на картинку.GIF

Comment: А конкретнее можно? Я делал то же самое, что работало вполне корректно.

Comment: Подробней я опишу, когда вернусь домой. Так как я не помню, в какую строку в свойствах я ее ставлю, хоть там другого выбора нет, но для точности ответа я напишу. Еще попробую поставить другую анимашку. Может, проблема с самим файлом. Если вы уж убеждены, что все должно работать.

Comment: Да вы правы. Моя ошибка была в том, что я делал ссылку на файл через свойства BackgroundImage в место Image. Спасибо